# Django - Passing multichoice field into POST dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `queryset` generated in my `forms.py` file that passes into my `template`.  The template result is a multichoice field based on the queryset.  The web browser presentation is correct - it renders the queryset as a drop down choice list that I can make a selection from.

Here is the `template` code:

```
<tr><td>{{ form.jury_name | placeholder:'Jury Name' }}</td></tr>
<tr><td><select>
    {% for item in form.parent_jury.field.queryset %}
        <option name="parent_jury" value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select></td></tr>
```

This is all contained in a `table`.

When the `form` is submitted (`method = "POST"`) the `POST` dictionary has all the correct values for the keys except the `parent_jury` key which posts a value of `''`.

I've worked through several SO solutions on the `views.py` side, but they don't change the fact that the information available for a `clean()` is missing the choice field value for `'parent_jury'`.  How do I get the selected option from the list to attach to the `'parent_jury'` key?

Comment: Shouldn't you declare the `name` on the `select`? I think by declaring it on the `<option>` the browser probably passes it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your rendered HTML is not the way it is supposed to be: the `name="..."` should be part of the `<select>` tag, *not* the `<option>s`:

```
<tr><td>{{ form.jury_name | placeholder:'Jury Name' }}</td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="parent_jury">
    {% for item in form.parent_jury.field.queryset %}
        <!-- remove the name here -->
        <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select></td></tr>
```

(of course you can remove the `<!-- comment -->` part (this is only meant to draw attention to this change).

Comment: yes - `name` placement was the problem - thanks - I only wish I would have asked 3 hours ago...

Comment: @BillArmstrong: well unfortunately I can not help with asking things three hours earlier :)